# Why should I complete my profile?

Tags: discussion

Why should people take the time to complete their profiles?

Answer (score 4):

There's probably no good reason, in the sense that someone can be a perfectly useful member of this community without ever revealing a single fact about themselves. The best reason to do so is (duh) that you want people to know something about you. Particularly if you're tired of being asked whether you're *that* Robin Laws... :)

Answer (score 3):

1. It shows you are part of the community and are here to stay. Its a base level of commitment.
2. You get a badge
3. You get enough reputation to actually do stuff like vote which is a core aspect of the community.
4. You get to have your own picture if you want.

Comment: 1. Given that you can fill it with complete and obvious nonsense, I disagree! 2. OK, maybe. 3. Rep is not that hard to get. I've only just filled in mine, and I'm over 200. 4. Hmm, OK. If you want...

Answer (score 2):

Vanity and/or building a sense of knowing the other community members.